# Как связать между собой процессы?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

У меня есть процессы: (условно) 1. Main - главный процесс 2. First - процесс, где исполняется первая функция 3. Second - процесс, где исполняется вторая функция. Можно ли как то связать эти процессы между собой т.е что бы я мог получить в Main данные из First и Second?

Comment: multiprocessing.Queue()